# Flutter how to update Listview.builder if the data is changes

Tags: flutter, listview, auto-update, stream-builder

I'm working with a **ListView.builder** in Flutter. For now all was working fine, I have the follwing lines of code in the callback methods:

```
@override
void initState(){
  items = new List();
  for(int index = 0; index < dataList.length; index++){
    items.add(...creating widget ..);
  }
}

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
    child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
       shrinkWrap: true,
       itemCount: dataList.length,
       itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container(
            width: width,
            height: 160 ,
            key: UniqueKey(),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: items[index],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

The problem is when the data of the **dataList** is updated, how should I implement this list to make the list update the **UI** if the data values are updated, removed or place changed. Is StreamBuilder the solution?

Comment: in your case it is dataList right?

Comment: @jitsm555 yes, sorry!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's continuously changing then use `StreamBuilder`

Eg: https://bendyworks.com/blog/a-month-of-flutter-rendering-a-list-view-with-stream-builder

If not then you can use `FutureBuilder`

Eg: https://medium.com/nonstopio/flutter-future-builder-with-list-view-builder-d7212314e8c9

OR,

If dataList gets change inside application(remove/update), then call `setState()` which will update `ListView`

Comment: Is continously changing but I solved this problem with a ChangeNotifier in the class definition of dataList items. The problem is when this items are removed or index changed. Which option I should use?

Comment: how they are removing or modifying? its done inside app or on server?

Comment: Inside app, depending on user interaction.

Comment: so whenever dataList gets modified you just have to call setState(), it will update the listview

Comment: @JiteshMohite Can u help me to solve this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76331842/flutter-streambuilder-doesnt-automatically-update-listview-when-new-data-come