# Flutter : StreamBuilder doesn't automatically update ListView when new data comes

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, riverpod, stream-builder

In my chat application I am trying to update the list automatically when there is an update/new data in the backend.I am using StreamBuilder to do that, but it's not updating the ListView when the backend data changes. I am using a spring boot server with mysql as database on the backend server side.Most of the chat application example I found are based on a firebase as server, which didn't help me to solve the issue.What I am doing wrong here, please help to correct the problem since i am a beginner in flutter.

```
class ChatScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
final dynamic data;
final dynamic category;
const ChatScreen({
    Key? key, required this.data, required this.category,
}) : super(key: key);

@override
ConsumerState<ChatScreen> createState() => _ChatScreenState();
}

class _ChatScreenState extends ConsumerState<ChatScreen> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

dynamic dataItem;
List<dynamic>? chatList = [];

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
  child: WillPopScope(
    child: showChat(),
   ),);
}

showChat() {
  return StreamBuilder<dynamic>(
  stream: ref.watch(chatControllerProvider).getChatsList(widget.data['id'],widget.category['id']),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      return const Loader();
    } else if(snapshot.data!.isEmpty) {
      return NoChat();
    } else {
      dataItem = snapshot.data!['chatRoom'];
      chatList = snapshot.data!['chatList'];
      return showChatView();
    }
  },);
}

showChatView() {
  int dataLength = chatList!.length;
  return Column(
    children: [
      Expanded(child: ListView(
        reverse: true,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        children: List.generate(chatList!.length, (index) {
          return MessageBox(
            data: chatList![dataLength - 1 - index],
          );
        },),
      ),),
    ],
  );
}

}

import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

import '../../chat_repository.dart';

final chatControllerProvider = Provider<ChatController>(
(ref) {
    final chatApi = ref.watch(chatRepositoryProvider);
    return ChatController(chatApi: chatApi, ref: ref);
},
);

class ChatController {
ChatController({
    required ChatApi chatApi,
    required ProviderRef ref,
})  : _chatApi = chatApi,
        _ref = ref;

final ChatApi _chatApi;
final ProviderRef _ref;

Stream<dynamic> getChatsList(int roomId,int categoryId) async* {
    var result = await _chatApi.getRoomChatList(roomId,categoryId);
    yield result;
}
}

import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import '...../chat_api.dart';

final chatRepositoryProvider = Provider<ChatApi>((ref) {
return ChatApi();
});

class ChatApi{
late Dio dioRest;

ChatApi() {
    dioRest = Dio(
    BaseOptions(
        headers: {
        HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: ContentType.json.value,
        },
    ),
    );
}

Future getRoomChatList(int roomId,int categoryId) async {
    try {
    token = getToken();
    var result = await dioRest.post(token.baseUrl!+'..../getRoomChatList',options: Options(.....),
        queryParameters: {'roomId' : roomId,'categoryId' : categoryId},
    );
    if (result.statusCode == 200) {
        return jsonDecode(result.data);
    }
    throw DioError(requestOptions: result.requestOptions);
    } on DioError catch (error) {
    if (error.response!.statusCode! >= 400) {
        throw TokenException(message: "Token invalid or expired");
    }
    throw BusinessException(BusinessError.fromJson(error.response?.data), statusCode: error.response?.statusCode);
    } catch (error) {
    throw Error();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: It looks like you're polling, not getting a stream.  This is inefficient.  Since you stated elsewhere that you're not using Firebase, you'll need to identify how to get an update stream from your database.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz I am using a spring boot server with mysql as database on the backend server side

Comment: I'm told you need to look in to "ServerSentEvent" in that case.  Look at the flutter_client_see  package

Answer (score 1):

From your code snippet, it seems like you're only fetching the chat list once in your `getChatsList()` function in `ChatController`. However, in a real-time chat application, you'll want to listen for updates from your backend as new messages arrive.

The method `getChatsList()` in the `ChatController` returns a `Stream` but you're yielding the result of a single API call wrapped with `async*` and `yield`, which won't automatically update when there's new data.

To use a practical exemple I'll assume you're using Firebase, a common way to keep your chat updated in real-time is by using the `onValue` event listener. When using `onValue`, Firebase will automatically call your callback function every time the data changes, allowing your chat to update in real-time.

Here is an example of how to use it:

```dart
Stream<dynamic> getChatsList(int roomId,int categoryId) {
  return _chatApi.getRoomChatList(roomId, categoryId).asStream();
}

Future getRoomChatList(int roomId,int categoryId) async {
  try {
    token = getToken();
    DatabaseReference chatRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance
        .reference()
        .child('rooms')
        .child(roomId.toString())
        .child(categoryId.toString());

    chatRef.onValue.listen((event) {
      var data = event.snapshot.value;
      // process data as needed
      return data;
    });

  } catch (error) {
    throw Error();
  }
}
```

In the above example, a listener is added to the Firebase database reference for the specific chat room. Any changes to that location in the database will trigger the `onValue` event and update your data in real-time.

This is just a generic example. You'll have to adjust the database reference according to your specific Firebase database structure.

Now since I doubt you're using Firebase or a similar real-time database, but a  REST API instead, then real-time updates are more complex and may involve other technologies like WebSocket, Server-Sent Events (SSE), or push notifications. You'll need to check if your backend supports any of these or not.

Comment: I am not using firbase here,

Comment: I understand it was for illlustrating my propositions I hope it is clear

Comment: I am using a spring boot server with mysql as database on the backend server side

Comment: In that case there are 2 efficient solutions:
1. Server Sent Event as mentioned higher in the comments which allows constant connection to the server allowing sending and receiving data all along. Downside is it require constant connection to the server.
2. Push Notification: Notifying your app with a change in the backend for it to update the data. This wouldn't require a persistent connection, but it would require setting up a service like Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM).

Comment: Ok I implemented Server Sent Event and its working as expected, but i don't know how to build & update the chat list based on the sse stream collected.Please have a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76340891/how-to-build-and-update-listview-using-realtime-data-from-server-sent-event-sse