# How to build and update Listview using realtime data from Server Sent Event (SSE) Stream using Dio package

Tags: flutter, dart, server-sent-events, flutter-provider, stream-builder

In my chat application I am trying to update the list automatically when there is an update/new data in the back-end. For that I implemented a Server Sent Event (SSE) using Flux on my Spring Boot back-end server and which is working fine and sending the data at each second as below.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getRoomChatList",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public Flux<ServerSentEvent<String>> getRoomChatList(@RequestParam("roomId") String roomId,@RequestParam("categoryId") String categoryId){

    return Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
            .map(sequence -> ServerSentEvent.<String> builder()
                    .id(String.valueOf(sequence))
                    .event("periodic-event")
                    .data(getRoomChatUpdateList(Long.parseLong(roomId),Long.parseLong(categoryId)))
                    .build());
}
```

Below is my API class which receive this SSE data using dio() which is also working fine.

```
class ChatApi{
late Dio dioRest;

ChatApi() {
    dioRest = Dio(
    BaseOptions(
        headers: {
        HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: ContentType.json.value,
        },
    ),
    );
}

Future getRoomChatList(int roomId,int categoryId) async {
  try {
    token = getToken();
    Response<ResponseBody> result = await dioRest.post(token.baseUrl!+'..../getRoomChatList',options: Options(.....),
        queryParameters: {'roomId' : roomId,'categoryId' : categoryId},
    );
    StreamTransformer<Uint8List, List<int>> unit8Transformer = StreamTransformer.fromHandlers(
      handleData: (data, sink) {
        sink.add(List<int>.from(data));
      },
    );

    result.data?.stream
      .transform(unit8Transformer)
      .transform(const Utf8Decoder())
      .transform(const LineSplitter())
      .transform(const SseTransformer())
      .listen((event) {
        // print the sse result every second
        print("Event: ${event.id}, ::  ${event.data}");
        return jsonDecode(event.data);
      }
    );
    throw DioError(requestOptions: result.requestOptions);
  } on DioError catch (error) {
    if (error.response!.statusCode! >= 400) {
        throw TokenException(message: "Token invalid or expired");
    }
    throw BusinessException(BusinessError.fromJson(error.response?.data), statusCode: error.response?.statusCode);
  } catch (error) {
    throw Error();
  }
}

}
```

How can I pass this realtime data to the chat screen where the Listview is implemented? And also how can I stop/disconnect this SSE stream connection when I exit from the the chat screen?

I am using StreamBuilder with riverpod to build the chatlist, but it's not updating the ListView when the back-end data changes.

```
class ChatScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
final dynamic data;
final dynamic category;
const ChatScreen({
    Key? key, required this.currentUser, required this.data, required this.screen, required this.selCategory,
}) : super(key: key);

@override
ConsumerState<ChatScreen> createState() => _ChatScreenState();
}

class _ChatScreenState extends ConsumerState<ChatScreen> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

dynamic dataItem;
List<dynamic>? chatList = [];

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
  child: WillPopScope(
    child: showChat(),
   ),);
}

showChat() {
  return StreamBuilder<dynamic>(
  stream: ref.watch(chatControllerProvider).getChatsList(widget.data['id'],widget.category['id']),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      return const Loader();
    } else if(snapshot.data!.isEmpty) {
      return NoChat();
    } else {
      dataItem = snapshot.data!['chatRoom'];
      chatList = snapshot.data!['chatList'];
      return showChatView();
    }
  },);
}

showChatView() {
  ......
}

}

import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

import '../../chat_repository.dart';

final chatControllerProvider = Provider<ChatController>(
(ref) {
    final chatApi = ref.watch(chatRepositoryProvider);
    return ChatController(chatApi: chatApi, ref: ref);
},
);

class ChatController {
ChatController({
    required ChatApi chatApi,
    required ProviderRef ref,
})  : _chatApi = chatApi,
        _ref = ref;

final ChatApi _chatApi;
final ProviderRef _ref;

Stream<dynamic> getChatsList(int roomId,int categoryId) async* {
    var result = await _chatApi.getRoomChatList(roomId,categoryId);
    yield result;
}
}

import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import '...../chat_api.dart';

final chatRepositoryProvider = Provider<ChatApi>((ref) {
return ChatApi();
});
```

Please help to correct the problem since I am a beginner in Flutter.